# Checkbox not changing state dynamically in material design and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, material-design

switches and I want to control their states dynamically through angularjs controller.
But it is not working as expected.

I have the problem replicated on the following codepen. Can anyone help quick?

```
<html ng-app="">
    <head >
        <!-- Material Design Lite -->
        <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.5/material.min.js">            </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.5/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
        <!-- Material Design icon font -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    </head>
    <body ng-init="check={}">
        <label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input" ng-click="check.set=!check.set" />
            <span class="mdl-switch__label"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-2">
            <input type="checkbox" id="switch-2" class="mdl-switch__input" ng-model="check.set" ng-checked="check.set"/>
            <span class="mdl-switch__label"></span>
        </label>
        {{check.set}}
    </body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjWQZb

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get your codepen to open but I created a plunker with your example. I have updated it to show how to set checkbox values from your controller. If you set the ng-model for your checkboxes, you can define the values from the controller.

http://plnkr.co/edit/zovPe9Zvzl0u3VElRvbI?p=preview

```
<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input" ng-model="check[0]" />
  <span class="mdl-switch__label"></span>
</label>
<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch-2" class="mdl-switch__input" ng-model="check[1]"/>
  <span class="mdl-switch__label"></span>
</label>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.check = [];

  // Set value
  $scope.check[0] = true; 
  $scope.check[1] = false;
});
```

There are more optimum ways of doing this but it is enough to get you started.